# conditionally parse data returned to ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm  trying to return associative array to an ajax success method from a php
what I'm doing is something like this

```
if(!empty($error)){
$rs = json_encode(array(
  'TYPE' => '0',
  'ERROR' => "<h5> Opps there was some error(s) </h5> " . $error 
  
));
    print_r($rs);
```

}

I'm encoding them in my php and parsing them in my ajax like this :

```
   $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: {name,age,id,submit},          
        success: function (data) { 
            var rs = JSON.parse(data);
            if (rs['TYPE'] == '0') {
                $('.alert').html(rs['ERROR']).show("slow");
            } else {
                console.log(rs);

            }
            
        },
        fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("error" + error)
        }
    });
```

but when i have a different type of data that i don't want to parse , how can i do that
because parsing them throws some uncaught errors
my data type is a data retrieved from mysql data base and if im getting them with parsing this
error pops up : Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
without parsing it works fine
here is my php mysql data :

```
include 'connection.php';
  $sql = "Select * from user";
  if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      $output [] =  $row["id"] .":". $row["name"];
    }
}
mysqli_close($link);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
print_r( json_encode($output));
```

what i want to return from my php is an associative array
that has 2 or more keys something like

```
array( 'error' => 'there was some errors '.$error , 'type' => '0' );
```

and i want to be able to access them back in my javascript and the type off the data i'm getting back
and conditionally parse them or not some thing like this :

```
success : function(data) {
       if(data['TYPE'] == '0'){ JSON.parse(data) //rest of my code } else{// my rest of code }
   }
```

but i seem i'm not able to access the returned data by keys before i can parse them

I'm sorry but i'm still a beginner and highly would appreciate any sort of help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

[print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is intended as a debugging tool only. It's inappropriate to use it to output your JSON in the normal course of your script. It adds extra formatting and thus will make the JSON invalid, and un-parseable by the JavaScript code.

Just use `echo` instead, as per the standard way to output from PHP.

Comment: i actually did echo , but when i'm returning array echo throws the exceptions , but it works fine with print_r !!!! ?

Comment: i figured it out , i just need to change my returned array signature to something like this :  if(!empty($error)){ // this signature works wonderful and parsing works great 
    $rs [] = ['TYPE'=>'0' , 'ERROR'=> "<b>There was some error(s)</b><br>".$error]; 
       echo json_encode( $rs ) ;
  }e